# Python/Tkinter - clear the graphical interface screen

Tags: python, tkinter

i am developing an application to calculate some taxes and show the result in the graphical interface. The code itself works perfectly, but if i use numbers with bigger squares, the result overlaps over the previous one. My question is, is it possible to clear the previous result and calculate the new one?
Follow the complete code below:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()


l_vlrRec = Label(root, text='Receita')
l_vlrRec.place(x=10, y=10)
e_vlrRec = Entry(root)
e_vlrRec.place(x=75, y=10, width=75)


def calcular():

    receita = float(e_vlrRec.get())

    l_result = Label(root, text='{:.2f}'.format(receita))
    l_result.place(x=10, y=150)

    e_vlrRec.delete(0, END)


bt = Button(root, text='Calcular', command=calcular)
bt.place(x=10, y=50)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You should create the `l_result` label in the main block and update its text inside `calcular()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the label's `textvariable` and also you don't have to instantiate a new Label every time the button is pressed:

```
v_result = DoubleVar()
l_result = Label(root, textvariable=v_result)
l_result.place(x=10, y=150)

def calcular():
    v_result.set(round(float(e_vlrRec.get()),2))
```

You can do the same for your `Entry` object `e_vlrRec` so you don't have to cast the string you get by calling `e_vlrRec.get()` but use the variable's `get()` instead

Without using `textvariable` you can also reconfigure the label's `text` parameter:

`l_result.configure(text='{:.2f}'.format(receita))`

or

`l_result['text'] = '{:.2f}'.format(receita)`

Comment: you should point out that `textvariable` isn't required - you can update the text on widget without it.

Comment: @BryanOakley For sure this is not the only way, but because he uses the values for calculation I would prefer this. But i will add the `configure` way to complete it